# php excute command asterisk in linux

Tags: php, linux, asterisk

i try to execute command linux in php below :

```
exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels"',$out);
print_r($out);
```

but, no display anything. if you use the following code.

```
exec('ls -la',$out);
print_r($out);
```

The browser displays the output as in the console. can help??

Comment: add `2&>1` at the end of the command. you might get errors.

Comment: Like this: `asterisk -rx "core show channels" 2&>1`. It will redirect the error output to the regular output.

Comment: not give error. not display anything

Answer (score 3):

As @Gerald Schneider said, you can try to redirect stderr to catch possible errors:

```
exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels 2>&1"',$out);
```

But I suspect that the asterisk binary is not in the `$PATH` or at least not in a path accessible by PHP interpreter.

You can try inserting the full path (`/usr/sbin/asterisk`, usually):

```
exec('/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "core show channels 2>&1"',$out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using excapeshellcmd()

```
$command = "core show channels";
$excape = excapeshellcmd($command);
exec('asterisk -rx $excape',$out);
print_r($out);
```

check this link [excapeshellcmd()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is fundamentally wrong to execute privileged command like `asterisk` from PHP - your web server may not be able to do so, and if you configure it to be able to, you potentially open up big security hole. Also, executing external commands from PHP is inherently slow.

Instead, you should use **[Asterisk Manager Interface](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239)** (AMI). AMI has bindings to many languages including PHP.

You can find example here: [http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Command](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example%3a+Command)

Another example might look like this (borrowed from [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example%3a+PHP)):

```
<?php

$socket = fsockopen("asterisk-server","5038", $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: admin\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: mypassword\r\n\r\n");

fputs($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: core show channels\r\n\r\n");
$wrets=fgets($socket,256);

?>
```

The only slight inconvenience of this solution is necessity to configure Asterisk Manager Interface, which may not be enabled by default in your Asterisk instance.

Comment: @bugfixer: well that's not enough info to tell what's wrong. Like I said, you need to configure AMI first, which is separate task in itself

Answer (score 0):

Note, your web server usually run under apache

Not think you can run that command from apache user. So you have fix access (in asterisk.conf file change user or in httpd.conf) and try again